# Images don't animate with their frames when animating VStack height change

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to make a simple collapse/expand item by using a VStack with conditional items in it.

When the new items are added to the vstack, the height of the vstack grows, the elements that were already present move up, and the new items fade in. However, an image that was part of the elements already present, animates at a different rate than the text it's with (or even it's frame as seen by coloring the background).

Is there a way to make the image animate correctly? Alternatively, is there a way to make the vstack expand down, as opposed to expanding from the middle, therefore keeping me from needing to animate the information that is already there?

Here's what I'm seeing, where the image background is colored purple:

[image: screen capture of buggy behavior]

Code:

```
struct Item: View {
    @State private var collapsed = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
               Image(systemName: collapsed ? "iphone" : "globe")
                .opacity(collapsed ? 1 : 1)
                .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 2).repeatCount(1))
                .background(Color.purple)
                Text("Main text")

                Spacer()
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation(.linear(duration: 2)) {
                    collapsed.toggle()
                }
            }
            
            if !collapsed {
                HStack {
                    Text("\(Image(systemName: "pencil")) Edit this thing")
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your case images are two different symbols (which you replace in-place of one drawing Image) - how do you expect this one image to be animated?

Comment: @Asperi I expect the position of the image to be animated with its background (e.g. the purple square), instead it shows up in its final location immediately